# How to wait for either of two timers to finish (Boost Asio)

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-asio, boost-coroutine

The code below prints to the console when *both* `timer1` and `timer2` have finished. How can I change it to print when *either* `timer1` or `timer2` finishes, **and then cancel the other timer.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>

int main() {

  boost::asio::io_context io;

  boost::asio::deadline_timer timer1(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
  boost::asio::deadline_timer timer2(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(1));

  boost::asio::spawn(io, [&](boost::asio::yield_context yield){
    timer1.async_wait(yield);
    timer2.async_wait(yield);
    std::cout << "Both timer1 and timer2 have finished" << std::endl;
  });

  io.run();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took the question to mean "how do you `async_wat_any(timer1, timer2, ..., yield)`.

The other answer is correct in pointing at callback completion-handlers to provide this, but they don't provide the glue back to a single coroutine.

Now [Asio's async operations](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/asynchronous_operations.html) abstract away the difference between all the invocation styles (callback, use_future, use_awaitable, yield_context etc...) - bringing them all back under the "callback" style essentially.

Therefore you can make your own async intiation that ties these torgether, rough sketch:

```
template <typename Token>
auto async_wait_any( std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<timer>> timers, Token token) {
    using Result =
        boost::asio::async_result<std::decay_t<Token>, void(error_code)>;
    using Handler  = typename Result::completion_handler_type;

    Handler handler(token);
    Result result(handler);

    for (timer& t : timers) {
        t.async_wait([=](error_code ec) mutable {
            if (ec == boost::asio::error::operation_aborted)
                return;
            for (timer& t : timers) {
                t.cancel_one();
            }
            handler(ec);
        });
    }

    return result.get();
}
```

Now in your coroutine you can say:

```
timer a(ex, 100ms);
timer b(ex, 200ms);
timer c(ex, 300ms);

async_wait_any({a, b, c}, yield);
```

and it will return when the first one completes.

### Let's Demo

Also, making it more generic, not hard-coding the timer type. In fact on a Windows environment you will be able to wait on Waitable Objects (like [Event, Mutex, Semaphore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/synchronization-objects)) with the [same interface](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/windows__basic_object_handle/async_wait.html):

```
template <typename Token, typename... Waitable>
auto async_wait_any(Token&& token, Waitable&... waitable) {
    using Result =
        boost::asio::async_result<std::decay_t<Token>, void(error_code)>;
    using Handler = typename Result::completion_handler_type;

    Handler completion_handler(std::forward<Token>(token));
    Result result(completion_handler);

    // TODO use executors from any waitable?
    auto ex = get_associated_executor(
        completion_handler,
        std::get<0>(std::tie(waitable...)).get_executor());

    auto handler = [&, ex, ch = completion_handler](error_code ec) mutable {
        if (ec != boost::asio::error::operation_aborted) {
            (waitable.cancel_one(), ...);
            post(ex, [=]() mutable { ch(ec); });
        }
    };

    (waitable.async_wait(bind_executor(ex, handler)), ...);

    return result.get();
}
```

We'll write a demo coroutine like:

```
int main() {
    static auto logger = [](auto name) {
        return [name, start = now()](auto const&... args) {
            ((std::cout << name << "\t+" << (now() - start) / 1ms << "ms\t") << ... << args) << std::endl;
        };
    };

    boost::asio::io_context ctx;
    auto wg = make_work_guard(ctx);

    spawn(ctx, [log = logger("coro1"),&wg](yield_context yield) {
        log("started");

        auto ex = get_associated_executor(yield);
        timer a(ex, 100ms);
        timer b(ex, 200ms);
        timer c(ex, 300ms);

        log("async_wait_any(a,b,c)");
        async_wait_any(yield, a, b, c);

        log("first completed");
        async_wait_any(yield, c, b);
        log("second completed");
        assert(a.expiry() < now());
        assert(b.expiry() < now());

        // waiting again shows it expired as well
        async_wait_any(yield, b);

        // but c hasn't
        assert(c.expiry() >= now());

        // unless we wait for it
        async_wait_any(yield, c);
        log("third completed");

        log("exiting");
        wg.reset();
    });

    ctx.run();
}
```

This prints **[Live On Coliru](https://wandbox.org/permlink/eBXzHQhIAdnSLSux)**

```
coro1   +0ms    started
coro1   +0ms    async_wait_any(a,b,c)
coro1   +100ms  first completed
coro1   +200ms  second completed
coro1   +300ms  third completed
coro1   +300ms  exiting
```

### Notes, Caveats

Tricky bits:

- It's hard to decide what executor to bind the handlers to, since there could be multiple associated executors. However, since you're using coroutines, you'll always get the correct `strand_executor` associated with the `yield_context`
- It's important to do the cancellations before invoking the caller's completion token, because otherwise the coroutine is already resumed before it was safe, leading to potential lifetime issues
- Speaking of which, since now we post async operations outside the coroutine with the coroutine suspended, we will need a work-guard, because coroutines are not work.

Comment: Thank you so much @sehe. Yes I was asking for an implementation of `async_wait_any`. This is a super helpful answer.

Comment: What is this syntax called? `(waitable.cancel_one(), ...);` I've never seen it before.  Great answer.

Comment: @MHebes That's a C++17 fold expression: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/spawn.hpp>

void print_timer_expired( bool& flag)
{
 if( flag )
     return;
 flag = true;
 std::cout << "Timer1 or timer2 has finished" << std::endl;
}
int main() {

  boost::asio::io_context io;
  bool flag = false;  // true if message has been printed

  boost::asio::deadline_timer timer1(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
  boost::asio::deadline_timer timer2(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(1));

  boost::asio::spawn(io, [&](boost::asio::yield_context yield){
    timer1.async_wait(yield);
    print_timer_expired( flag );
  });
  boost::asio::spawn(io, [&](boost::asio::yield_context yield){
    timer2.async_wait(yield);
    print_timer_expired( flag );
  });

  io.run();

}
```

Comment: Thanks @ravenspoint. Sorry I should have been more specific, but I don't want "Timer1 or timer2 has finished" to print twice. I.e., once one of the timers finishes, I want to cancel (or just ignore) the other. Is this possible?

Comment: I'm really confused why this answer isn't simply [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/HU2LcZl8L2A8zRgT)? In other words it feels like it basically says "don't use coroutines" or at least doesn't answer the question of how do you `async_wait_any(timer1, timer2, yield)`, which is how I read the question

Comment: Added an [answer of my own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66927688/85371) that shows what I was expecting to see. See it [Live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/eBXzHQhIAdnSLSux)

Comment: @sehe I read the question as " How can I change  it ( my code ) to print when either timer1 or timer2 finishes" That is, a minimal modification to implement the feature without introducing am enormous collection of bells and whistles.

Comment: Fair enough. In that sense [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/HU2LcZl8L2A8zRgT) is better still. I think it's no longer a feature at all, since you split the coro. The control flow is the entire goal. Yes, you could read the prose description in the narrow sense, but that's... missing the forest for the trees.

Comment: I think it best to read the question and answer what the OP wrote.  You can rush off and guess what the OP was really trying to do, in your opinion, but if you guess wrong  the situation will become hopelessly confused..

Comment: I couldn't agree more.